# Can zipped files be detected as pirated material?

Tags: zip

Are zipped files resistant to being found containing copyright material? I don't understand the nature of compression and whether the uncompressed file is still visible in any manner.

Answer (score 0):

They are resistant if they are encrypted, but if it's not encrypted you can still read the contents without unzipping it. Dropbox/Google/whoever might check it just to see what's inside, but I doubt they will unzip it and then check the contents of another zip file. Plus, if you encrypt both sets, they wouldn't be able to (unless they allocated resources to cracking the password for every zip file they process).

If you want to be sure they won't be read, zip them into split files with a password, then zip all the multiples into another zip with a password.